# Read one key and continue further automatically

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have this code:

```
var read = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // Reading Integer from console
if (read == 1) // If read equals some value
{
    // Do Something
}
```

And I want make that if I press some key, it will go further immidiately without pressing enter to confirm it in the console. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Console.ReadKey`.

```
var read = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString());
```

Comment: @PolluxPollux correct..I jsut corrected it. Please check my update.

Comment: Nice! It works! But I have a question, how can i hide the key that i pressed in console?

Comment: What do you mean by saying to hide it?

Comment: If i press that key, it will write to the console.

Comment: This can be done by passing the value `true` to the Cosnole.ReadKey(), `var read = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString());`